# android compose bottomnavigation item is hide

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

If I add floating action button to the bottom bar in bottomnavigation as extended, the menu will be covered by location.
If I'm set up in the center, you can see both menus.
But if I leave it as end, you can only see one menu.
When I set it to end, I want to see both menus.

Here is my code

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            if (menu.name != null) {
                TopAppBarCompose(title = menu.name)
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                val route = Screen.BarcodeScan.route
                onNavigateToBarcodeScreen(route)
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.QrCodeScanner,
                        contentDescription = "BarcodeScan",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 30.dp, top = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp, end = 5.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Scan",
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp, top = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp, end = 30.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                cutoutShape = RoundedCornerShape(50),
                content = {
                    BottomNavigation {
                        BottomNavigationItem(
                            selected = selectedItem.value == "send",
                            onClick = {
                                content.value = "Send Screen"
                                selectedItem.value = "send"
                            },
                            icon = {
                                Icon(Icons.Filled.SwapVert, contentDescription = "send")
                            },
                            label = { Text(text = "send") },
                            alwaysShowLabel = false
                        )

                        BottomNavigationItem(
                            selected = selectedItem.value == "input",
                            onClick = {
                                content.value = "input Screen"
                                selectedItem.value = "input"
                            },
                            icon = {
                                Icon(Icons.Filled.Create, contentDescription = "input")
                            },
                            label = { Text(text = "Input") },
                            alwaysShowLabel = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
```

When I set in center, I can see two menu

[image]

But I set extened fab button to end, It's going to be as follows.

[image]

I want to set the place of the extended fab button to end and see two menus. Is there a way to change the place?

ps.The image was simply uploaded to help understand.

Comment: This seems like a bug. According to the [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom#specs), when using `FabPosition.End` items must be "aligned to opposite edge of the FAB". I suggest you [report this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks, Without using extended fab button, general fab button also causes the same case. According to the document, it should definitely be left-align, but I wonder why it is not. If there's an official example, I'd like to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to just offset the FAB using the offset modifier. Here's an example:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd) {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")

    BottomNavigation {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(item) },
                selected = selectedItem == index,
                onClick = { selectedItem = index }
            )
        }
    }

    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
        modifier = Modifier.offset(x = -10.dp,  y = -70.dp),
        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
        text = { Text("ADD TO BASKET") },
        onClick = { /*do something*/ }
    )
}
```

[image: FAB Offset]

---

**FAB inside a scaffold**

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val items = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")

Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
    floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.offset(x = -10.dp, y = -70.dp),
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
            text = { Text("ADD TO BASKET") },
            onClick = { /*do something*/ }
        )
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart) {
            BottomNavigation {
                items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(item) },
                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. Is there any way to Fab to Bottom Navigation in Box compose?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: @Joharn I mean, if in Scaffold, [isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true] put fab to bottomappbar. But I couldn't find isFloatingActionButtonDocked in Box. Is there a code in Scope that functions the same?

Comment: I added an example in my solution to show how to do this in a scaffold.

Comment: Okey, Thank you for your answers. First of all, I shouldn't do isFloatingActionButtonDocked .

Comment: Be sure to mark my solution as accepted. Thanks!